# error in React.Native hello world undefined is not a function(evaluating 'Object

Tags: reactjs, native

I just run a simple hello world demo in React.native and something went wrong.

This is code in , it's really easy. I guess there is something wrong with this.render

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>Hello world!</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is error info in red background of android simulator:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 
>   (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android 
>   &dev=true&minify=false:3573)

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong. It works fine on iOS and also on Android if you run it in the debugger. The problem appears to be with React Native. I was able to reproduce the issue with RN0.57.8.

Try recreating your project for a specific earlier version of React Native.

E.g.

react-native init --version="0.55.4" MyNewApp

Problems like this sometimes emerge when using the latest version of React Native sadly. I normally work with a version that's been out for a couple of months when starting a new project.

Comment: You're welcome. If have an option to accept my answer, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.